# Shutdown computer every day at 22 o'clock

Tags: batch-file

I want to shutdown my computer at 22 o'clock. I don't want to use task scheduler I want to do this using Batch file. Please Any one can help me ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the task scheduler?

Comment: Because i want to use this in my project So I can't use task scheduler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more gentle on computer resources and should do the task:
The `timeout` command is in Vista and later

```
 @echo off
 :W
 timeout /t 30 /nobreak
 echo %time% |find "22:00" >nul || goto :W

 shutdown.exe /s /f /t 60 /c "Go to bed!!!!!!"
```

Comment: simplicity is one of the most beautifull things in this life =]

Answer (score 1):

The technique to initiate the shutdown can be a lot of different things.
It consists of two things:

1) Scheduler (program/service that starts an action at a certain time)

2) Command (in this case the shutdown command.

My suggestion is to do the following:

Create a task in windows "task scheduler". 
Set trigger on "22:00 every day"
Actions: "Start a program" point it to your batch file.

Batchfile
Use a command like: "Shutdown -s -f -t 01"
With that command your pc will be shutdown without notice and with force (hanging applications will be ended). Perhaps you can change the timeout to an higher number so window will alert you with a popup.

EDIT:
Your suggestion of placing batch file in startup only executes when you login, it doesn't run continously" (sorry, haven't got the reputation to comment)

Comment: do you know any tip which start computer automatically at morning at certain time

Comment: To start a computer. To make it simple, most BIOS settings support boot at certain time. Check your BIOS first. Otherwise you have to start it remotely using wake-on-lan for example

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I got answer Write this in batch file  put batch file in startup folder

```
 @echo off
     :W
    if %time%==22:00:00.00 goto :X
    goto :W
     :X
    shutdown.exe /s /f /t 60 /c "Go to bed!!!!!!"
```

Comment: This is too precise when comparing the time - the batch file can miss the exact millisecond, and a second problem is that it will use a lot of cpu time without a delay of some kind.